# Exchange ActiveSync - get unseen emails count

Tags: exchange-server, email-client, activesync

I am writing Exchange ActiveSync client in C++. I use *FolderSync* command for synchronize list of folders and *Sync* command for synchronize emails from server.

In IMAP protocol I use command *STATUS INBOX (UNSEEN)* for getting unseen emails in inbox folder.

Is in Exchange ActiveSync some equivalent command ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998357(v=exchg.160).aspx) only the following is part from ActiveSync:

```
Support for HTML messages
Support for follow-up flags
Conversation grouping of email messages
Ability to synchronize or not synchronize an entire conversation
Synchronization of Short Message Service (SMS) messages with a user's Exchange mailbox
Support for viewing message reply status
Support for fast message retrieval
Meeting attendee information
Enhanced Exchange Search
PIN reset
Enhanced device security through password policies
Autodiscover for over-the-air provisioning
Support for setting automatic replies when users are away, on vacation, or out of the office
Support for task synchronization
Direct Push
Support for availability information for contacts
```

But you might wish to implement something via EWS (see here some [example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vikas/2007/11/30/howto-ews-update-isread-flag-for-items-using-exchange-web-services/)).